# Set input values to values found in URL parameters with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have multiple types of inputs (checkbox and number). They have unique values, but grouped together using `data-filter-group` too. I have JS to update the URL with parameters when each is changed. So the URL may look like this:

https://example.co.uk/product-configurator/?input=ac_3_phase%2Cac_1_phase&output=ac_3_phase&battery_voltage=10%2C720

**Breakdown of the URL**
`?input=` - input is the `data-filter-group` value from the input field.
`?input=ac_3_phase%ac_1_phase` - two values have been selected, so are separeted with `%2C` in replacement of a comma. `ac_3_phase` and `ac_1_phase`.

`&output=` - output is the `data-filter-group` value from the input field.
`&output=ac_3_phase` - one value selected in this example. `ac_3_phase`. You'll notice there are other

`&battery_voltage=` - the `data-filter-group` value from the input field.
`&battery_voltage=10%2C720` - two values set: `10` and `720` in this example.

First set of inputs:

```
<input class="form-check-input filter-input" type="checkbox" value="ac_3_phase" id="flexCheckDefault-385" data-filter-group="input">
<input class="form-check-input filter-input" type="checkbox" value="ac_1_phase" id="flexCheckDefault-385" data-filter-group="input">
```

Second set of inputs:

```
<input class="form-check-input filter-input" type="checkbox" value="ac_3_phase" id="flexCheckDefault-412" data-filter-group="output">
<input class="form-check-input filter-input" type="checkbox" value="ac_1_phase" id="flexCheckDefault-230" data-filter-group="output">
```

> *Notice they are 'grouped' using the `data-filter-group` attribute and value.

More inputs, but these are `input type="number"`, not checkboxes:

```
<div class="input-group">

    <input type="number" value="0" step="10" class="form-control filter-input-number" data-filter-group="battery_voltage">
    <input type="number" value="720" step="10" class="form-control filter-input-number" data-filter-group="battery_voltage">

</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g0y2rxnh/4/

**What I am trying to achieve**.
If someone visit the page with the URL parameters already set, I need all relevant inputs to be set to the values found in the url. Make note that some inputs have the same values such as `ac_3_phase` appears twice, this is why I grouped them using `data-filter-group`.

My attempt: This doesn't yet take into account I also have number inputs, and also how some parameters have multiple values set too. Same for the number inputs, as you can see in the JSFiddle I have a FROM and TO inputs.

```
// Retrieve the URL search parameters
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);

// Loop through the URL search parameters and their values
params.forEach((value, key) => {

    // Loop through each key
    const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(`[data-filter-group="${key}"]`);

    console.log(inputs);
    
    // Loop through each input
    inputs.forEach(input => {

        // Check if the input value matches the URL parameter value
        if (input.value === value) {

            // Check the input
            input.checked = true;

        }

    });

});
```